# Window.onload not working on page being loaded into base page

Tags: javascript, html, onload

So there is an index.html page, and a navbar.html page. navbar.html gets loaded into the index.html page

```
 $(".include-nav-bar").load("share/navbar.html");
```

window.onload works fine on the base page (index.html), but, randomly works on the loaded in page (Note, I don't have onload on the base page, I only have onload on the navbar.html page)

The onload inside the navbar page randomly works after maybe the 3rd reload, I suspect its because the base page is overriding it or something.

Is there a way to get that second onload to work inside the loaded Index page? (Correctly any way, and not randomly)

Comment: jquery.load has a callback handler which fires at the same time. window.load is not fired for documents loaded through xhr

Comment: Tried $( document ).ready() ? https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @imanshu15 Brilliant, that worked perfectly thank you. You mind adding it as an answer so I can mark it as answered.

Comment: If you want that the window.load of `navbar.html` occurred in `index.html` you can use `iframe` instead of  `$(".include-nav-bar").load("share/navbar.html");` Although I recommend to prevent iframe for this reason and manage your code by `jQeury` on `document.ready` in `index.html`. You can split html and script of your navbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$( document ).ready()` function.

Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).on( "load", function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

Here is the documentation.
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: This is pointless. If the load event doesn't work, then it is because the document has already loaded. The document will be ready **before** it is loaded. This only appears to work because jQuery will fire new ready handlers immediately if the document is already ready. You can dispense with the event handler and just run the code directly for the same effect. It isn't waiting for anything.

Comment: The purpose of the ready event is that it should occur as early as possible after the document has loaded, so that code that adds functionality to the elements in the page doesn't have to wait for all content to load. Isnt that what he wanted? if not i am sorry

Comment: "as early as possible after the document has loaded" — This is **before** the load event fires. The load event has already fired. `$( document ).ready(() => foo());` could be rewritten as just `foo()` for the same effect. Using a ready handler here is pointless.

Comment: @Quentin Can confirm, just tested it now. I removed the event handler and it still worked. 

You, sir, are correct.